# Why can Gibbon Gem access API but can't listSubscribe()?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, mailchimp, gibbon

I'm trying to get mailchimp integrated with my ruby-on-rails app using the Gibbon gem.

I've successfully accessed the API. I tested it by getting a list of all my mailchimp lists. However, I'm running into problems with the listsubscribe method. I'm not getting any errors, it just isn't working at all.

I have the following code in the controller for the page where users sign up, after the user is made and their information can be accessed.

```
gb=Gibbon::API.new
gb.listSubscribe({:id => "the-id-for-list", :email_address => user.email, :update_existing => false, :double_optin => false, :send_welcome => true, :merge_vars => {'FNAME' => user.first_name, 'LNAME' => user.last_name, 'MERGE3' => user.subscription, 'MERGE4' => DateTime.now}})
```

It does nothing. I've tried playing around with the parameter phrasing (à  la this post:[How do you use the Gibbon Gem to automatically add subscribers to specific interest groups in MailChimp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500631/how-do-you-use-the-gibbon-gem-to-automatically-add-subscribers-to-specific-inter)) I've tried structuring it more like in this tutorial: http://www.leorodriguez.me/2011/08/subscribe-member-into-mailchimp-using.html

I have no idea what's going wrong. As I said before, other API calls are going through to MailChimp. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using the current released gem version of Gibbon, or the unreleased 0.5.x branch?

Comment: @DylanMarkow The 0.5.x branch. I take it you are suggesting I should be on a different branch? Updating to this branch was the fix I got to get accessing Gibbon at all working from someone else here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228587/why-does-gibbon-throw-uninitialized-constant-gibbonapi-nameerror/17332596#17332596 Looks like that thread was updated and it isn't the one I should be using. I'll try to back up to a previous version of the gem and see if it helps.

Comment: @DylanMarkow I don't think that is the problem. I can't run the server with the older branch of Gibbon, as it gives my Gibbon::API.method_name methods uninitialized constant errors when I use the older version from rubygems.com. With the 0.5.0 version from github, I don't get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had the code in the wrong place. I was not putting it where users were actually being created, but in the code to generate the view to ask users to sign up. Once I moved it to where the user was actually created, it worked fine.

Comment: Accept your own answer then ;)